# Print \n newline as actual newline in python pdb

Tags: python, pdb

When I am in pdb and I have a large string, sometimes I'd like to print it out with newlines as actual newlines, instead of seeing them as \n in the terminal.

```
(Pdb) p large_string
"very large string with newline\nanother line in the large string\n\netc\n"
```

I'd rather see

```
(Pdb) printwithnewline large_string
"very large string with newline
another line in the large string

etc
"
```

Any tips?

Comment: (while you're at it with printing stuff in pdb, you should also check `pp` which does pretty print, that's very handy for lists and dicts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just call the normal print function:

```
(Pdb) print(large_string)
very large string with newline
another line in the large string

etc
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 2.x you can import the print function:

```
from __future__ import print_function

(Pdb) print(large_string)
very large string with newline
another line in the large string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix any Python command with '!', so this will also work for Python 2.x:

```
!print large_string
```